# Simplification of consecutive `map`s

Tags: haskell

I've written the following code:

```
{- ...
   ...
   ... -}

data Ellipsoid
data Halfplane
data Intersection

data PointSet s a where
    Halfplane :: RealFrac a =>
                 a -> a -> a -> (a -> a -> Bool) -> a ->
                 PointSet Halfplane a
    Ellipsoid :: RealFrac a =>
                 a -> a -> a -> (a -> a -> Bool) -> a ->
                 PointSet Ellipsoid a
    Intersection :: [PointSet s a] -> PointSet Intersection a

type TestFunc a = RealFrac a => (a -> a -> a ->  Bool)

test :: (Show  a) => PointSet t a -> TestFunc a
test (Ellipsoid a b c f r) = f'
                       where f' z y x = ((x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 + (z/c)^2) `f` r
test (Halfplane a b c f t) = f'
                       where f' z y x = (a*x + b*y + c*z) `f` t
test (Intersection ps) =     f'
        where f' z y x = and . map ($ x) $ map ($ y) $ map ($ z) ts
              ts = map test ps
```

In particular I'd like to have input on `f' z y x = and . map ($ x) $ map ($ y) $ map ($ z) ts`, whether there is a way to express this more succinctly.

Of course, I'm happy about any other comment as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
and . map ($ x) . map ($ y) . map ($ z) . map test $ ps
```

contains several `map` calls connected with `.`. But since `map f . map g === map (f . g)`, we can simplify it as

```
and . map (($ x) . ($ y) . ($ z) . test) $ ps
```

or more concisely

```
and . map (\g -> test g x y z) $ ps
```

Also `and . map p` can be simplified by `all`, so finally we get

```
all (\g -> test g x y z) ps
```

Just one more note, please post code that compiles, especially for CR, it's much easier to work with; see http://sscce.org/

Comment: Thank you! (So at least I had the right feeling that this *is* simplifiable. The simplified version is also more readable. Exactly what I wanted. I have to learn more identities.  --  And thanks for the pointers, I'll bear SSCCE in mind for future posts! (in this case it was only the language extensions, but I see how this must have been annoying).